# Why the first iteration is more time-consuming in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to calculate how much time our model takes in every iteration.

I'm using pytorch.

Here is the code.

```
for i, (inp, gt) in enumerate(test_loader):
    inp = torch.zeros((1,3,224,224)).cuda()
    print('The %d-th iteration' % (i))

    time_start = time.clock()

    with torch.no_grad():
        _, _, pred = generator(inp, inp)
        
    time_end = time.clock()
    time_gap = time_end - time_start
    time_sum = time_sum + time_gap
    time_cnt = time_cnt + 1
    print("ave : %.10f,  single : %.10f" % (time_sum/time_cnt, time_gap))
```

But find that the first iteration always takes more time.

Here is the results.

```
The 0-th iteration
ave : 0.0360450000,  single : 0.0360450000
The 1-th iteration
ave : 0.0284930000,  single : 0.0209410000
The 2-th iteration
ave : 0.0253540000,  single : 0.0190760000
The 3-th iteration
ave : 0.0239062500,  single : 0.0195630000
The 4-th iteration
ave : 0.0224336000,  single : 0.0165430000
The 5-th iteration
ave : 0.0220561667,  single : 0.0201690000
The 6-th iteration
ave : 0.0211392857,  single : 0.0156380000
The 7-th iteration
ave : 0.0204987500,  single : 0.0160150000
The 8-th iteration
ave : 0.0204487778,  single : 0.0200490000
The 9-th iteration
ave : 0.0198066000,  single : 0.0140270000
The 10-th iteration
ave : 0.0198207273,  single : 0.0199620000
The 11-th iteration
ave : 0.0195461667,  single : 0.0165260000
The 12-th iteration
ave : 0.0195166923,  single : 0.0191630000
The 13-th iteration
ave : 0.0193250714,  single : 0.0168340000
The 14-th iteration
ave : 0.0192459333,  single : 0.0181380000
The 15-th iteration
ave : 0.0194143750,  single : 0.0219410000
The 16-th iteration
ave : 0.0194283529,  single : 0.0196520000
The 17-th iteration
ave : 0.0192986111,  single : 0.0170930000
The 18-th iteration
ave : 0.0194028947,  single : 0.0212800000
The 19-th iteration
ave : 0.0192675500,  single : 0.0166960000
The 20-th iteration
ave : 0.0193315714,  single : 0.0206120000
```

I'm curious about the reason.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first `.cuda` call will allocate memory on the GPU which will be used again by the consecutive iterations. This is certainly the reason why the first iteration takes longer. You may try to force-release the allocated memory (with [`torch.cuda.empty_cache`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.empty_cache.html) on each iteration and compare the times with your initial measures.

Comment: so as long as the size of the input does not change per iterations, pytorch will keep using the same allocated memory, just transferring the new input tensor to it? so the over head of allocation is not there?